# UIMA RUTA Matching-mmHg

Tags: uima, ruta

I tried to  match "mmHg" using Regex in UIMA RUTA SCRIPT but it's not matching. I used the following rules:

```
W{REGEXP("mmHg")->MARK(ME_UNITSPACING)};
ANY{REGEXP("mmHg")->MARK(ME_UNITSPACING)};
ANY+?{REGEXP("mmHg")->MARK(ME_UNITSPACING)};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE LOWERCAMELCASE,ME_UNITSPACING;
Document{-> RETAINTYPE(SPACE)};
SW CW{->MARK(LOWERCAMELCASE,1,2)};
Document{-> RETAINTYPE};
LOWERCAMELCASE{REGEXP("mmHg")->MARK(ME_UNITSPACING)};
```

Sample Input:

```
mmHg
small City
fishBowl
```

Comment: Just to highlight the reason why the rules int he question did not work: The initial seeding/the basic tokens are intended to be minimal/atomic. Thus, mmHg is not one token but two and therefore the REGEXP will never match.